# Performance of counting associations through join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models Person and Organization.
They are linked together via a join table organizations_persons

Organization.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :persons, -> { where(:persons => { is_deleted: false }) }, join_table: :organizations_persons
```

When fetching whole Organization tree (using ActsAsTree gem), I'm also including person count in view for each organization.

I'm having ~200 organizations, 1500 persons and 2500 records in the join table.

It takes ~900ms to build the whole tree without including membercount.
When im including membercount it takes ~3500ms with organization.persons.size, ~2500ms with organizations.persons.distinct.size and with raw sql, when using the same sql that rails generates with organizations.persons.size, ~1100ms.

organizations.persons.size generates this sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `persons` INNER JOIN `organizations_persons` ON `persons`.`id` = `organizations_persons`.`person_id` WHERE `persons`.`is_deleted` = 0 AND `organizations_persons`.`organization_id` = 81
```

organizations.persons.distinct.size generates this sql:

```
SELECT `persons`.* FROM `persons` INNER JOIN `organizations_persons` ON `persons`.`id` = `organizations_persons`.`person_id` WHERE `persons`.`is_deleted` = 0 AND `organizations_persons`.`organization_id` = 81
```

Is there anyway I can speed up association counting without using raw sql?
I'm using rails 4.2

Comment: You could try my gem https://github.com/trialbee/association_count. But I do not think it will give you much of a boost...

Comment: You could also cache this by having a counter in your organization. that is updated whenever a person is added or removed.

Comment: I guess that using custom counter_cache is the way to go, like @Albin said.